# bootgrid jquery select row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-bootgrid

I'm using Bootgrid jquery in my asp.net mvc , and i'm trying to make row selectable  , i tried what i found on the net but it still not working , it shows up without the selection feature

```
<table class="table  table-condensed table-hover table-striped col-md-12" id="tbl-Produits">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <td data-column-id="Nom">Nom du Produit</td>
            <td data-column-id="Type"> Type du Produit</td>

            <td data-column-id="LastVersion">Dernière version </td>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ProduitsGrid = $("#tbl-Produits").bootgrid({
            ajax: true,
            selection: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            rowSelect: true,
            url: "@Url.Action("getall")",.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a data-identifier="true" set for one column.
As the documentation says:

> Ensure that the data attribute data-identifier="true" is set on one
>   column header.

[See here](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/examples#basic-selection)